# Is it possible to open Fancybox with custom event in mootools

Tags: jquery, mootools, fancybox

I have the custom mootools event below , would it be possible to open an image URL in Fancybox (jQuery) ? ::: And if its possible any idea how to go about this :::

```
events: {
    click: function() {
        var tubeObject = this.getParent().retrieve("tubeObject");
        var tubeObject = this.getParent().retrieve("tubeObject")
        var fullurl = tubeObject.full;

            milkbox.openWithFile({ 
                href:'http://localhost/square/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/34.jpg', 
                title:''+fullurl+''
            });
    }
```

Say I'd want to "call" HTML as example below instead of the milkbox.openWithFile :::

```
html: "<a class='fancybox' rel='fancybox' href='http://localhost/images/test.jpg' >View Image</a>"
```

Comment: you seem to have milkbox open on your event. i take it this needs to go to fancybox instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This does not solve my initial Question but might still be of interest**

I did not think this was going to be an easy solution considering my lack of javascript (moo & j) ::: My only other option was to use a "moootools" plugin & integrate it into the rest of the wP theme ::: I removed the milkbox plugin & replaced it with "imagezoom"

I replaced this :::

```
milkbox.openWithFile({ 
    href:'http://localhost/square/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/34.jpg', 
    title:''+fullurl+''
});
```

With This bit of code :::

```
//http://bertramakers.com/moolabs/imagezoom.php
var imagezoom = new Imagezoom({
    image: fullurl,
    x: ydcoza_imagezoom_x, //custom global variables
    y: ydcoza_imagezoom_y,
    rel: ydcoza_lightbox
});
imagezoom.show();
```

I then created a couple of variables in my functions.php file for the X & Y configuration :::

I also popped this into my custom scripts (.js) file , to set rel=lightbox on all image links :::

```
/***************************************************
        Add rel:'lightbox' to image links
 ***************************************************/
jQuery("a[rel!='ignore']").each(function() {
    this.rel += 'lightbox';
});
```

I thank @Dimitar for his effort in trying to resolve this, his code although not working for me got me thinking about above solution :::

Answer (score 0):

looking at the api, the example goes:

```
    $.fancybox({
        //'orig'            : $(this),
        'padding'       : 0,
        'href'          : 'http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2687/4220681515_cc4f42d6b9.jpg',
        'title'         : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut' : 'elastic'
    });
```

so you could try:

```
    jQuery.fancybox({
        'orig'          : jQuery(this), // pass on the el
        'padding'       : 0,
        'href'          : this.get("href"), // get url
        'title'         : this.get("title") || "",
        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut' : 'elastic'
    });
```

Comment: I tried it earlier but it does not work & yes I want to substitute milkbox (mootools) with fancybox

Comment: Maybe this will help , Firebug gives me the following break ::: **jQuery.fancybox is not a function** :::